# How to Publish a SharePoint site on the internet

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, shared-hosting

I have a WSS SharePoint site that i need to deploy and publish to that Users will be able to access it through the internet.
I know this is possible, but how do i go about getting this done?
Does anyone have some good articles?

Kind Regards
Etienne

Answer (score 2):

From [Microsoft Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2006/08/08/planning-designing-amp-securing-an-extranet-and-internet-facing-wssv3-and-sharepoint-server-2007-environments.aspx), essentially a page linking to relevant articles.

You can also download the [SharePoint Planning Services Starter Kit](https://iwsolve.partners.extranet.microsoft.com/SDPS/ProgramOverview.htm#StarterKit)